# Retag request - merge [hotmail] into [outlook.com]

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

Hotmail was greatly overhauled last year, and one part of the revamp was that its name changed from Hotmail to Outlook.com. However, the tag wiki for [hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) (286 questions) is obsolete and the tag wiki for [outlook.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) (65 questions) still states that they will soon be merged (that merger happened a year ago). Consequently, [hotmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hotmail) should be merged into [outlook.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) and the former should be a synonym of the latter.

Comment: Oh, god. People use hotmail?

Comment: @bjb568 Hotmail is no more...

Comment: You are free to kill me for my saying this, but I actually hate Gmail...literally...

Comment: Oh, I hate it too. The UI is bad, and I'm afraid of Google looking at my emails for targeted ads…

Comment: I don't ever log into my webmail. I always use email clients.

Comment: I use apple mail. The app and the service.

Comment: You should also submit a suggested tag wiki edit.

Comment: To be pedantic, Outlook.com existed before Hotmail was shut down. When Hotmail was shutdown all users were forced to move to Outlook.com (although they got to keep their `hotmail.com` address.) I'd also suggest that perhaps a good number of those old [tag:hotmail] questions should be closed because they'll no longer apply to a closed service.

Comment: The question is why do we even have a [hotmail] tag? Do we really need it? (not sure from a quick glance through the tag)

Comment: SYNONYM. No point retagging, just make Hotmail a synonym of Outlook as they are now the same thing. Safest/simplest way to keep these small tags in-sync and the Hotmail one disappear

Comment: @AlE. It did exist, but was in a limited beta program. It was officially released once Hotmail was decommissioned.